# How can I wrap a glyphicon with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyph, font-awesome

How can I wrap a glyphicon and a word together so that the icon is centered over or under the word. For an example:

```
    <div class="row">
   <div class="span4">
<div style="font-size: 60px;">
<i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> </p>
 <h1>Photography </h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="span4">
 <div style="font-size: 60px;">
 <i class="icon-camera"></i> </p>
  <h1>Rentals</h1>
  <p></center></p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="span4">
 <div style="font-size: 60px;">
 <i class="icon-star-empty"></i> </p>
 <h1>Dance Media</h1>
 <p></center></p>
   </div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to put `text-align: center;` in the div that contains the text and the icon. Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rahjU/11/